# Which library is best for plotting 150000 data points at a time in Angular 8

Tags: angular, plot, visualization

I have a large data set (150000 data points ) to be plotted against time. Currently, I am using Chart.js. But I was not able to plot more than 120000 points using Chart.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

uplot can be used for plotting 150000 data points. Please refer to https://github.com/leeoniya/uPlot.